# Implement offline routing on OSM map

Tags: android, routes, openstreetmap, graphhopper

I want to implement the routing functionality on my custom map which is .map format.

I have found this link https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper which probably solves the problem, but I can not understand how to integrate it with my OSM map and POIs ( Points Of Interest ) on it.

I know there are a lot of questions on Stackoverflow, but I was not able to find a solution or suggestion. Any help, like examples or tutorials will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just pass the current location as start and the POI coordinate as end location to graphhopper. Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Hello, and thanks for a response! Graphhoper uses .ghz format from which it takes ~6 files like edges, geometry, map, ... but I have a .map and POIs, so it's different format.

Comment: Sorry for maybe a stupid question, but I new in offline mapping.

Answer (score 1):

(1) if you just use the original graphhopper code, please ensure your data dump satisfy the OSM feature scheme(please refer to https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features). If not, you need to modify the to code to feed your data. You can check the example data file in the source code(/graphhopper/core/files/andorra.osm for reference.

(2) graphhopper can run in different mode, for your case, mobile devices. Check he specific instruction for android, https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md